# How to fix on macOS Vim powerline error after removing Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, macos, vim, homebrew

I removed Ruby on my Mac using:

```
brew remove -f ruby
brew cleanup
```

Homebrew displayed a message that "Vim has a Ruby dependency, do I still want to remove Ruby (y/N)", and I chose "y" and Ruby was removed.

Then I installed Ruby again with:

```
brew install ruby
```

After that Vim started to give me errors when starting:

```
vim .
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:17:in `require': incompatible library version - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin18/stringio.bundle (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:1230:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:1230:in `<module:Gem>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:116:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `require'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
  File "/Users/ruslan/.vim/bundle/powerline/powerline/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from powerline.lib.config import ConfigLoader
  File "/Users/ruslan/.vim/bundle/powerline/powerline/lib/config.py", line 11, in <module>
    from powerline.lib.threaded import MultiRunnedThread
  File "/Users/ruslan/.vim/bundle/powerline/powerline/lib/threaded.py", line 7, in <module>
    from powerline.lib.monotonic import monotonic
  File "/Users/ruslan/.vim/bundle/powerline/powerline/lib/monotonic.py", line 19, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 555, in <module>
    _reset_cache()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 279, in _reset_cache
    CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(lambda: None)
MemoryError
An error occurred while importing powerline module.
This could be caused by invalid sys.path setting,
or by an incompatible Python version (powerline requires
Python 2.6, 2.7 or 3.2 and later to work). Please consult
the troubleshooting section in the documentation for
possible solutions.
Error detected while processing /Users/ruslan/.vim/bundle/powerline/powerline/bindings/vim/plugin/powerline.vim:
line  157:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 53, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 9, in powerline_troubleshoot
  File "/Users/ruslan/.vim/bundle/powerline/powerline/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from powerline.lib.config import ConfigLoader
  File "/Users/ruslan/.vim/bundle/powerline/powerline/lib/config.py", line 11, in <module>
    from powerline.lib.threaded import MultiRunnedThread
  File "/Users/ruslan/.vim/bundle/powerline/powerline/lib/threaded.py", line 7, in <module>
    from powerline.lib.monotonic import monotonic
  File "/Users/ruslan/.vim/bundle/powerline/powerline/lib/monotonic.py", line 19, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 555, in <module>
    _reset_cache()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 279, in _reset_cache
    CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(lambda: None)
MemoryError
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

After that I added the following lines to my ~/.vimrc:

```
let $RUBYHOME=$HOME."~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0"
set rubydll=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib
let g:powerline_pycmd = 'py3'
```

The error message when Vim starts has changed to:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/ruslan/.vim/bundle/vim-rubyhash/plugin/rubyhash.vim:
line   54:
E370: Could not load library /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib
E266: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Ruby library could not be loaded.
You need vim compiled with Python 2.6, 2.7 or 3.2 and later support
for Powerline to work. Please consult the documentation for more
details.
E370: Could not load library /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib
E266: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Ruby library could not be loaded.
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I also tried:

```
brew uninstall vim ruby
brew cleanup
rbenv global system
brew install vim ruby
```

But it hasn't helped.

My system:

```
macOS => Mojave

vim --version => 
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 19 2019 19:08:44)
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283, 1365

which vim => /usr/bin/vim
which ruby => /Users/myname/.rbenv/shims/ruby
ruby -v => ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-darwin18]
python3 --version => Python 3.7.7
```

I could not find any sources that help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

macOS comes with a command-line version of Vim preinstalled:

```
l /usr/bin/vim
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   2.0M Jan 23 06:58 /usr/bin/vim
```

It's set-up to work with the version of Ruby preinstalled for their own purposes:

```
l /usr/bin/ruby
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    36K Jan 23 06:59 /usr/bin/ruby
```

So, it's not necessary to install a different version of Ruby, or Vim as they'll work together.

If you want a more recent version of either, Homebrew can install them, as you found out, however from that point you should rely on them as a pair. Deleting the Homebrew-installed Ruby now has your Vim confused because the Ruby it sees is what Apple installed and is probably an older version than it wants:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:17:in `require': incompatible library version - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin18/stringio.bundle (LoadError)
```

So, you could use one of these:

- Uninstall your Homebrew Vim, then use the Vim and Ruby Apple installed.
- Uninstall your Homebrew Vim, then reinstall Ruby and Vim using Homebrew and ignore Apple's installed versions.
- Do the first, then install [MacVim](https://macvim-dev.github.io/macvim/), which is what I use, and which works with Apple's Ruby or one under the control of [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or [RVM](https://rvm.io/). This is what I recommend.

Because of Vim's ability to load scripts from anywhere, you can easily create a `.vimrc` and `.gvimrc` in your home directory, and point Vim to plugins saved into a directory there. I have `~/.vim` containing many plugins, and all are usable with Apple's Vim, MacVim's CLI `vim` and their GUI version of GVim, and NVim. (My `.vimrc` and `.gvimrc` are actually soft-links to `~/.vim/vimrc` and `~/.vim/gvimrc` just to keep everything in one neat pile.) I use rbenv, and can update Rubies as I want and it chugs away. Occasionally I'll have to tweak something for "[Seeing Is Believing](https://github.com/JoshCheek/seeing_is_believing)" after updating, but it is an easy fix.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice. But as I have mentioned in the description I already tried to uninstall and reinstall homebrew vim and ruby and it did not help. I do not like macvim and want my vim work as before. It is very strange that there is no way to fix it.

Comment: Well, like I said, even nVim and Apple's Vim picks up everything from my rbenv Ruby and plugins, so I can't point a finger there.